# Does anyone recognise this effect? Is it half toning?

Tags: photoshop-effects

I'm trying to recreate this effect in Photoshop (attached image); does anyone recognise the effect, and know how to recreate it?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It could be a halftone. To do something similar:

1. Convert the document to grayscale, using `Image › Mode › Grayscale`.
2. Convert the document to a bitmap, using `Image › Mode › Bitmap`.
3. Set the method to halftone.

[image]

4. Set the shape to line.

[image]

5. Convert back to RGB, by choosing `Image › Mode › Grayscale` then `Image › Mode › RGB Color`.
6. Add a gradient map. :)

[image]

Comment: Nice cat. Yours?